# Does LINQ to XML replace XSLT?

Tags: xslt, linq-to-xml

Is there anything you can do in [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Transformations) that can't be done in [LINQ to XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_XML)?  Is it still important to learn XSLT?  When would you choose one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there anything you can do in XSLT that can't be done in Linq to XML?

No, since LINQ to XML is an API used by Turing-complete programming languages, and covers more of XML Infoset than XSLT document model does (e.g. you can fully control the difference between text and CDATA nodes in L2X).

> Is it still important to learn XSLT?

Depends on what you're doing. Broadly speaking, yes.

> When would you choose one over the other?

XSLT is generally better when you need to do a transformation - i.e. both input and output is XML. There are a number of reasons for that. First of all, XSLT pattern matching is usually more concise than nested `?:` in L2X queries, and far more readable. You can also use `*` to great effect to set up a default rule (like "copy everything", or "process children but do not generate output"), and then add rules for specific nodes you need to process in a special way - thus you do not need to write explicit loops/comprehensions for each node level in the document, as you often do in L2X. Finally, XPath is also more concise than L2X queries (at least in C#), so if you do a lot of non-trivial querying, it's likely to be far shorter and more readable in XSLT.

L2X is generally better when you need to quickly query a document for some value or node. The main advantage here is that there's less runtime overhead (XPath needs to be parsed, L2X query does not), and you don't need to mess with `XmlNamespaceManager` and other cruft - the API is streamlined for writing single-expression queries. As well, having nested `from` loops and `let` brings it closer to XQuery territory.

L2X is also the only choice when you need an in-place update of the document, and may be better when you only need to replace a few values in the document, and in-place update is an option - since XSLT doesn't let you touch the input in any way.

Comment: It is a shame Microsoft declined to provide an XQuery processor in the framework. Because when you want a template engine, you can't really come up with a worse tool than XSLT.

Comment: From personal experience using both, XSLT is still better than XQuery for transforms - the main problem with the latter is the lack of anything equivalent to template pattern matching. It's definitely nice for querying, though.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely still important to learn XSLT. LINQ to XML is great, but it's use is limited to .NET Apps.

XSLT can be applied across languages and platforms...even browsers can take XML and apply an XSLT to generate an output.

Don't forget that some .NET Application API's (CMS systems for example) still require you to supply XSLT to transform internal XML into an output. Ignoring the technology all together would be, in my opinion, a real mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Not for anyone not using .NET